# can an child class access parent class property data?

Tags: php

I have a child class extending a parent class.

In my parent class have a protected property that stores config data. In the parent class this property has all the configuration files needed.

But in the child class I cannot access that data. How can I bring over the config property data into the child class?

I am using

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        print_r($this->config);
    }
}
```

but i get an empty response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the resource is Private you can

There are basically to ways to access the parent resource:

1. parent::{resource identifier}; eg. `parent::config;`
2. $this -> {resource identifier}; Unless the resource is overridden

---

Now, coming to the part, of which might cause this issue.

The parent constructor might need to run, in order to store the configuration. SO,

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        print_r($this->config);
    }
}
```

Comment: the parent class doesn't have a constructor, also the property is protected (i set it to public as well).

Comment: my code is kinda complicated, i would need to give you 20 different paste bin snippets to put it together =/

Comment: @Eli, Then thats all I can help

Comment: heh, thanks. but would not calling a constructor mean anything?

Comment: @eli... The code you have till now, is not the cause. I am confident about that. To tell rest of the story, I need more code.